# Error handling with express-graphql & react-apollo

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphql-js, react-apollo, express-graphql

I'm trying to display a simple "Email and password do not match" error on a login form, but am having trouble and not sure if where I've gone wrong is on the server or in my React app. I thought I'd post here as I'm unsure which github repo would be appropriate.
Here's the resolver on the server:

```
// Schema definition:

type Mutation {
   loginViewer(credentials: AUTH_CREDENTIALS): SignInPayload!
}

type SignInPayload {
   token: String
   expires: Int
   requiresReset: Boolean
}

// Mapping the mutation to the resolver:

Mutation: {
   loginViewer: loginViewerMutation,
},


// Resolver:

const loginViewerMutation = async (obj, args) => {
   const { credentials } = args
   const user = await User.findOne({ email })
   if (!user) throw new GraphQLError('Email and password do not match')
   const matches = await user.comparePassword(password)
   if (!matches) throw new GraphQLError('Email and password do not match')
   return createJWT(user)
}
```

Then, the mutation as it's called within my Login component:

```
const mutation = gql`
   mutation LoginViewer($password: String!, $email: String!) {
      loginViewer(credentials: { email: $email, password: $password }) {
         token
         expires
         requiresReset
      }
   }
`

export class Login extends React.Component {
   handleLogin = (credentials) => {
      this.props
         .mutate({ variables: { ...credentials } })
         .then(() => {
            // ...
         })
         .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.message)
            console.log(error.graphQLErrors)
            // ...
         })
   }

   render() {
      // ...
   }
}

export default graqphql(mutation)(Login)
```

Everything works as expected when I supply the correct information. When I don't, the error that is caught doesn't contain the GraphQLErrors.

I'm using the apollo-link-error middleware with the default setup: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/error.html

My console looks like this:

[image]

The expected authentication error is being returned, and logged from the middleware. But, in my Login component, the error.graphQLErrors array is empty.

Where might I be going wrong here?

- It doesn't seem right to be returning a 500 Internal Server Error --- it's behaving exactly as I want it to. Am I implementing this incorrectly on the server?
- How are the graphQLErrors getting 'lost' between the logging middleware and the .catch(error)?

Comment: Can you post the code where you connect `loginViewerMutation` to the resolver map or where you call it?

Comment: @TalZ, just updated the question with more code

Comment: I tried reproducing a similar error with my server and didn't succeed. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question on the express-graphql github repo, they quickly pointed out that the solution was removing the `!` on my `loginViewer` mutation:

```
// Schema definition:

type Mutation {
   loginViewer(credentials: AUTH_CREDENTIALS): SignInPayload!
}

// Should be:

type Mutation {
   loginViewer(credentials: AUTH_CREDENTIALS): SignInPayload
}
```

> It's expected behavior since your top-level field (loginViewer)
>   defined as non-null. That means when error bubble up it GraphQL engine
>   has no option except make data field equals to null:
>
> Since Non-Null type fields cannot be null, field errors are propagated
>   to be handled by the parent field. If the parent field may be null
>   then it resolves to null, otherwise if it is a Non-Null type, the
>   field error is further propagated to it’s parent field.
>
> If all fields from the root of the request to the source of the error
>   return Non-Null types, then the "data" entry in the response should be
>   null.
>
> http://facebook.github.io/graphql/draft/#sec-Errors-and-Non-Nullability
>
> If data is null that means the entire request is failed and
>   express-graphql response with 500.